# Wget problems downloading from datalogger with Samba server

Tags: c, shell, wget, information-retrieval

I need to download files (the ones with .dsc and .dat extensions) from a datalogger running with a Samba server on a battery with limited storage space so I must delete these files afterward.

I tried to use wget command wich seemed suited for this task but quite often while downloading, comes a moment when there is "no data received" for a file and "connexion refused" for all the following files.

I tried -c option but it say that it cannot find the index.html file (wich exists)

The datalogger running on battery, I'm looking for a way to get all these files with the lightest impact on battery.

Does anyone have suggestions, or alternatives more reliable than wget that could be used through a C program or a shell script ?

EDIT : Still no answer for the wget issue, for the moment I switched with httrack instead of wget as it seems to succesfully download everything more quickly.

Comment: Don't think you can use `wget` with samba shares.

Comment: @Rohan wget manages to connect and I retrieve few files. though it seems like it always stop around the same moment. I'm new to these kind of manipulations

Answer (score 0):

You can download files from Samba using a wget-like utility:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/smbget.1.html

Some command line parameters have different symbols (-r for continue instead of -c) but essentially it works the same. Hope it helps.